# Action.Submit validation #bot frameworkV4

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

My bot consists of adaptive card which has text box and submit.action,when user clicks on submit it does some action in the next dialog

Iam able to prompt the adaptive card and submit the action .

But i need 2things to be done here

1.for few cards when user go back and resubmit the form it has to submit with old data

2.when user go back and click submit it has to throw some prompt message saying card expired or submitted already

I an working with .net core,v4 and waterfall dialog
Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do this in the current state of the Bot Framework. Here's a couple of good options:

1. Use the [AdaptiveCardPrompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62269207/action-submit-validation-bot-frameworkv4). This isn't officially-supported, but I believe provides you with all of the customization you're looking for, out-of-the-box.
2. Attach your Adaptive Card to an [ActivityPrompt](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/ActivityPrompt.cs) and write a custom validator for it.

The trickiest part about your issue is collecting data from a card after the user has already completed the prompt. Once the prompt is over, there's no good way to use it. However, you could:

1. Add a card Id to the `data` property of the `Action.Submit`
2. Capture the input in `OnMessageAsync()`
3. If `Activity.Value` contains the card Id from step 1, handle it appropriately. Note, however, that it gets very difficult to use this within a dialog if the prompt has already completed.

Answer (score -1):

You can go through the following link for handling user action https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-actions?view=azure-bot-service-3.0